# Where are permissions table in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

I searching for the permissions defined for all users in the database. I know that in Drupal 7 it is in the role_permission table. Where can I find it in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Drupal 8, all roles and permission stores as configuration. If you want to see it in the Database, you can check the config table.

Your query should be like:

```
select * from config where name = 'user.role.subadmin';
```

Where subadmin is the role name. You will see a blob data which has serialize value for this role. All the permissions store in it.

As this is a configuration so, there is .yml file as well name "user.role.{your_role_name}.yml" in conf folder. In my case:

```
sites⁩/default⁩/⁨config⁩/⁨sync/user.role.subadmin.yml⁩
```